# Tip to get around error: can't access property "onkeyup", id(...) is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created some functions in js, something very simple, and instead of calling these functions directly in the html I decided to execute them looking for the input id.

It was like this:

```
...
functions here
...

function id(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
    window.onload = function(){
    id('name').onkeyup = function(){inicialMaiuscula(this);}
    id('phone').onkeyup = function(){mascara(this, mtel);}
    id('postalcode').onkeyup = function(){mascara(this, cepm);}
}
```

The problem is that this js file is loaded on different pages, so if the input with that `id` doesn't exist it returns the error:

```
can't access property "onkeyup", id(...) is null
```

And also on some pages the function works and on others it doesn't. Tips on how I can get around this?

I take the opportunity to ask another question, there are inputs that use the same function. How can I declare both `id` on the same line without having to repeat all the code?

Comment: As the error is saying, you first need to check if the `id()` call is returning a real Element or is returning `null`. One common way is to save the result of the call into a variable, check if that variable is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), and only set the `onkeyup` property if it is. `const name = id('name'); if (name) { name.onkeyup = ... }`. Additionally, I would recommend to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than the special `onkeyup` property.

Comment: Why add it to every page when it does not exist? Just causing the page to take longer to load to check to see if an element exists. But the answer is as simple as `id('name')?.onkeyup = function(){inicialMaiuscula(this);}` but the real answer is don't include it.

Comment: @epascarello This file really needs to be loaded on every page. Nice tip, very interesting and simple.

Comment: @romellem Thus? `id('nome')?.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
        inicialMaiuscula(this);
    });`

Comment: @epascarello you can't do an assignment with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). @Clebson, yes `id(...)?.addEventListener(...)` would work since `addEventListener` would only be called if the previous `id(...)` return was non nullish.

Comment: @romellem Hm.. Ok, do you know if I can pass two id's to use the same function without having to repeat the line?

Comment: Nice tip, yes it is. Modules make lives better. Simple includes. Not knowing the whole picture we can not give exact tips, just generic ones.

Comment: ...That completely negates the point of your helper. Maybe you are looking for something like [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and you can call it with `'#name, #phone, #postalcode'`. You'd need to loop over its returned NodeList to attach each event separately. If you find stuff like this tedious, (as old as it may be) maybe a library like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) could be useful? If you are interacting with the DOM imperatively, jQuery smooths out some of the rough edges of the DOM APIs.

Comment: What is up with not wanting to repeat code? What exactly are you trying to avoid?  I seem to be missing the second point of this question.

Comment: @epascarello I just wanted to simplify the code, so it doesn't get too long.

Comment: What is there to simplify? I am not seeing exactly code that repeats here.

Comment: Don't worry about that this early. Focus on getting everything working because you look to refactor / "simplify the code."

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: You are right, thank you so much for all the support. I'll focus on how it works from now on. At first everything is working fine with the tips provided so far.